# Dynamically load native embedded dll from C++/CLI (clr based) project/dll

Tags: .net, c++-cli, embed, native, .net-assembly

I have a C# Managed library (dll) that is calling into a C++/CLI (w/ /clr) library, in order to call some native library functions.

What i want to do is *embed* the *native* dll's in the C++/CLI libary/dll (in order to make a simply one library entity), and then dynamically load them (the native dll's).

I have been able to successfully *embed* them into the C++/CLI library, but i have no idea how to then use that data to dynamically load them. I tried using (AssemblyResolve and Assembly.Load), but i don't get a chance to use it *before* the attempted load of the C++/CLI libary returns "Could not load file or assembly" error.

I have read about the assembly initializer (appears a bit like dllmain). Do i need to set one up that then loads the embedded assemblies?

UPDATE:I have written up the code below to PULL the DLL out of the "resource" and dump it into a file, and that appears to be working fine.

```
{
  Assembly ^ CurrentAssembly = Assembly::GetExecutingAssembly();

  array<String^> ^ ResourceNames = CurrentAssembly->GetManifestResourceNames();

  String^ BaseDir = AppDomain::CurrentDomain->BaseDirectory;

  for (int i = 0; i < ResourceNames->Length; i++)
  {
    if ( ResourceNames[i]->EndsWith(".dll") )
    {
      Stream^ stream = CurrentAssembly->GetManifestResourceStream(ResourceNames[i]);

      if ( stream != nullptr )
      {
        array<Byte^> ^ assemblyData = gcnew array<Byte^>(stream->Length);

        FileStream^ fileStream = File::Create(BaseDir + ResourceNames[i]);
        stream->CopyTo(fileStream);
        fileStream->Close();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The Win32 API does not support loading native DLLs from memory. You need to have the file on disk to be able to use it. `Assembly.Load` and friends only support managed DLLs (aka assemblies).

So you'll have to extract the DLL to a temporary location, then use `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAdress` to use its APIs.

Here's a post describing how to do it: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jonathanswift/archive/2006/10/03/dynamically-calling-an-unmanaged-dll-from-.net-_2800_c_23002900_.aspx

Comment: Hi Igor, thanks for the information. Assuming as you say that there is nothing in managed to allow the loading of the libraries, the "link" is ok (though uses the old native interfaces) for the loading of the dll and the functions. However, it doesn't cover the taking of the "resource" stream for the embedded resource and getting that into a file. Also does anyone have any ideas for WHERE to put it?

Comment: Ok, i think i figured out the "dumping of embedded dll to file" part. See original question.